What does あんだから mean?

The context is two colleagues who work in a store, colleague B just got hired so he doesn't know the place, while colleague A is older. Upon entering a room together, colleague A exclaims:

鍵の管理あんだからさっさとしてくださいよ

to which B replies

ごめんごめんまだ覚えたいこといっぱいあってさ

"Sorry, sorry. There are still a lot of things I want to learn"
What does 鍵の管理あんだから mean? You are?
